# Recursively count number of sub-directories

Tags: command-line, directory

Is there any command or the group of commands that can count the number of all sub-directories recursively starting with the certain specific letter?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a combination of the `find` and `wc` commands

For example, to count the directories starting at the current directory `.` and starting with letter 's'

```
find . -type d -name 's*' -printf "1" | wc -c
```

The `-name` condition matches against the name of the directory, using shell pattern matching rules (it is also possible to match using *regular expression syntax*, however that would be overkill here). The `-printf "1"` part prints the character `1` each time a match is found, and `wc -c` counts these characters.

The choice of `1` as the character printed and counted is arbitrary.

---

To display *and* count, you could do

```
find . -type d -name 's*' | tee >(wc -l)
```

however be aware that the count may be inaccurate if any directory names include newline characters (rare - but legal).

Comment: what does -name actually does ?? and what does -printf "1" does in this case ??

Comment: @Abiral please see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

With python one-liner:

```
$ tree top
top
├── sub1
│   └── another_subdir
├── sub2
└── sub3

4 directories, 0 files

$ python -c 'import os,sys;print(sum([ 1 for r,s,f in os.walk(sys.argv[1]) for i in s if i.startswith("s")    ]))' ./top                             
3
```

The one-liner works as so:

- We're going to pass the directory which we want to traverse as command-line argument, and for that we need `sys` module, while for directory traversal we need `os.walk()` function - hence we need `os module.
- `print()` will print output of `sum()` which sums all items inside the list that we create via list comprehension (the `[i for i in iterable]` form).
- The list comprehension can be treated as two nested for loops. On each iteration `os.walk()` gives top directory, its subdirectories list, and its files list. When we iterate over `s` subdirectories list, we'll check if each subdirectory starts with letter `s` , via `.startswith()` method, and if it does, 1 will be put on to the list. Thus `sum()` will basically add up together a  long list of 1's.

Answer (score 0):

`find . -type d -not -path '.' -printf 0 | wc -c ;`

Recursively find all directories (-type d) within current directory (find .) that is not (.) directory and print 0 for each directory found. Then `wc -c` counts the number of characters (0) from the previous command output.