# how to count the number of directory and files recursively?

Tags: directory

How on earth can  i count all the directory and sub directories recursively including all the hidden files and directories accurately ?
I tried

```
ls -aR | wc -l
```

but this is not working accurately. 
Can anyone help me.. ??

Comment: Try `du -h *|wc -l`

Comment: Are you not able to modify [Count the number of directories recursively](http://askubuntu.com/questions/707408/count-the-number-of-directory-recusively) to meet your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find .|wc -l` will do the trick. This shows all files and directories from `.`(current dir). If you just want to have dirs try `find . -type d`. Note that this will count the current dir also.